# Couldn't find UserSession without an ID in ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#index

Couldn't find UserSession without an ID
Rails.root: C:/Sites/login_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:9:in `current_user_session'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:14:in`current_user'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__233847886_33215772'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in`index'

- class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_user private
  def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end
  def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end
  end
- class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  end
- class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  @user_session = UserSession.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user_session }
  end
  end

  def create
  @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user_session.save
      format.html { redirect_to(:users, :notice => 'Login Successful') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user_session, :status => :created, :location => @user_session }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user_session.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
  end
  def destroy
  @user_session = UserSession.find
  @user_session.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(:users, :notice => 'Goodbye!') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  end
  end
  end
- class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
  end

  def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
  end

  def new
  @user = User.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
  end
  def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to(:users, :notice => 'Registration successfull.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
    else
     format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
  end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end

- layout/apllication.html



  LoginApp
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>



      <% if current_user %>
      <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(current_user.id)%>
      <%= link_to "Logout", :logout%>
      <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path%> 
      <%= link_to "Login", :login %>
      <% end %>

  <%= yield %>
- user_seesion/_form.html
  <%= form_for(@user_session) do |f| %>
  <% if @user_session.errors.any? %>

  ### <%= pluralize(@user_session.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user_session from being saved:

    <% @user_session.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  - <%= msg %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>


  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_fields :password %>


  <%= f.submit %>

  <% end %>
- user_sessions/edit.html

  ## Editing user_session

  <%= render 'form' %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', @user_session %> 
  |
  <%= link_to 'Back', user_sessions_path %>
- user_sessions/index.html :

  ## Listing user_sessions

Username
    Password

<% @user_sessions.each do |user_session| %>
  
    <%= user_session.username %>
    <%= user_session.password %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', user_session %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_session_path(user_session) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', user_session, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New User session', new_user_session_path %>

- user_sessions/new.html

  ## Login

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', user_sessions_path %>

- user_sessions/show.html
  <%= notice %>

  **Username:**
  <%= @user_session.username %>

**Password:**
  <%= @user_session.password %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_session_path(@user_session) %> 
|
<%= link_to 'Back', user_sessions_path %>

-users/_form.html
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>

### <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:

```
  <ul><br/>
  <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %><br/>
    <li><%= msg %></li><br/>
  <% end %><br/>
  </ul><br/>
</div><br/>
```

<% end %>

<%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  
  
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  
  
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  
  
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    
  
    <%= f.submit 'create user'%>
  
<% end %>

- users/edit.html

  ## Editing user

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @user %>
 |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>

- users/index.html :

  ## Listing users

  <%= notice %>


  Username
  Email

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  
    <%= user.username %>
    <%= user.email %>
    <%= link_to 'Show', user %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
  
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>

- users/new.html :

  ## New user

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>

- users/show.html :
  <%= notice %>

**Username:**
  <%= @user.username %>

**Email:**
  <%= @user.email %>

**Crypted password:**
  <%= @user.crypted_password %>

**Password salt:**
  <%= @user.password_salt %>

**Persistence token:**
  <%= @user.persistence_token %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %>
 |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>

Comment: post your controller and view

Comment: oh no... you made a mess....

Comment: plz give me soln..... its urgent

Comment: giv me ur email id i vl mail u complet folder

Comment: @vinay ...plz give ur email id

Comment: For better understand you can just add your code to pastebin

Comment: @user2033013 post your routes file. you dont want to send the whole app . Just paste your route file and delete all these codes.

Answer (score 1):

In user_session.rb, you need to change the inherited class to Authlogic::Session::Base, like so:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
...
end
```

Also, next time use a gist or something similar to paste large chunks of code, or format it at least. Hope that helps!